# Creating duplicate row based combination of row values in Groupby Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, row, combinations

DF1

```
ID           Product  Key
C1   Product 2219 B1   B1
C1   Product 2219 B3   B3
C1   Product 2219 B8   B8
C2   Product 2210 B1   B1
C2   Product 2217 B8   B8
C2  Product 2230 B28  B28
```

Output DF

```
ID         Product       Key  Key_comb
C1 Product 2219 B1        B1    B1, B3
C1 Product 2219 B3        B3    B1, B3
C1 Product 2219 B1        B1    B1, B8
C1 Product 2219 B8        B8    B1, B8
C1 Product 2219 B3        B3    B3, B8
C1 Product 2219 B8        B8    B3, B8
C2 Product 2210 B1        B1    B1, B8
C2 Product 2217 B8        B8    B1, B8
C2 Product 2210 B1        B1   B1, B28
C2 Product 2230B28       B28   B1, B28
C2 Product 2217 B8        B8   B8, B28
C2 Product 2230B28       B28   B8, B28
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please explain what you are trying to achieve, and show what you have tried. Please re-review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: help is much appreciated